# Error: The provided `as` value (/path/name/) is incompatible with the `href` value (/path/name/mobile/[league])

Tags: next.js

**next.config.js**

```
 async rewrites() {
    return {
      beforeFiles: [
        {
          source: '/path/name',
          destination: '/path/name/mobile',
          has: [
            {
              type: 'query',
              key: 'device',
              value: 'mobile',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          source: '/path/name/:league',
          destination: '/path/name/mobile/:league',
          has: [
            {
              type: 'query',
              key: 'device',
              value: 'mobile',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

[image]

Above you can see structure of my project and `next.config.js` file `rewrites` function . It throw me error you see in name of this task. When I remove second object from my `rewrites` function , it start to work , but it seems correct for me , what I've written , what am I doing wrong ?

**_middleware.ts**

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const isMobile = (userAgent: string) =>
  /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(userAgent);

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const userAgent = req.headers.get('user-agent');

  if (userAgent) {
    if (isMobile(userAgent)) {
      const device = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('device');

      if (!device) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${req.nextUrl.href}?device=mobile`);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    source: '/path/name/:league/',
    destination: '/path/name/mobile/:league/',
```

Above you can see solution , if you add some query params to url with dynamic params , you should close it with `/`